# 4 Dimensional Numerical Integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have a pretty complicated function:

```
Mfff[s1_, 
  s2_] := -(1/ 
    w) (-(((-1 + w) Log[16])/(-1 + w + w (-1 + x1) x1)^2) - 
     Log[(1 - 2  y1)^2] + Log[1 + s (-1 + y1) y1] + 
     Log[1 + t (-1 + y1) y1] + Log[1 + u (-1 + y1) y1] + 
     1/(-1 + w + w (-1 + x1) x1)^2 (-1 + 
        w) (-2 Log[(-1 + w + w^2 (-1 + x1) x1)/(-1 + w + 
           w (-1 + x1) x1)] - 
        Log[(-1 + w + w^2 (-1 + x1) x1 + 4 y1 + 4 (-2 + w) w y1 - 
          4 (-1 + w)^2 y1^2)/(-1 + w + w (-1 + x1) x1)] + 
        Log[(16 (-1 + w + w^2 (-1 + x1) x1 + s y1 + s (-2 + w) w y1 - 
            s (-1 + w)^2 y1^2))/(-1 + w + w (-1 + x1) x1)] + 
        Log[(-1 + w + w^2 (-1 + x1) x1 + t y1 + t (-2 + w) w y1 - 
          t (-1 + w)^2 y1^2)/(-1 + w + w (-1 + x1) x1)] + 
        Log[(-1 + w + w^2 (-1 + x1) x1 + u y1 + u (-2 + w) w y1 - 
          u (-1 + w)^2 y1^2)/(-1 + w + w (-1 + x1) x1)])) /. { 
   u -> -s1 - s2 + 4/3, s -> s1 + 4/3, t -> s2 + 4/3}
```

and using that I need to perform the following computation:

```
f2[l_, s1_] := 
 Gamma[1/2]^2*(2 l + 1) / (2 Pi) * Sqrt[(s1 - 8/3)/(s1 + 4/3)] 
NIntegrate[(Mfff[s1, 1/6 (3 s1 (-1 + x) - 8 x)] GegenbauerC[l, 1/2, x] // Simplify), {x,-1,1}, {w, 0,1}, {x1,0,1}, {y1, 0 ,1}]
```

for different values of $s_1$. I have tried the Global Adaptive strategy with working precision = 200, MaxRecursion = 20 and MaxErrorIncreases = 5000; MonteCarlo method (with MaxRecursion = 200) and a Local Adaptive strategy. For the first two, my integral fails to converge (but gives me a result within 4 minutes), while the latter doesn't give me any result even after waiting for a couple of hours.
I would like two things from my code: the integral should converge and that it should do in some reasonable time (say, 30 minutes). This is because this computation needs to be performed to as great a numerical accuracy as possible, and has to be performed a lot of times for different values of $s_1$.

EDIT : I plan to use $s_1$ in the range (2.7, 4) and $l$ can take only the values 0 or 2; changing `ReplaceAll` did not lead to significant reduction in time.

Comment: And l, the first argument of f2, should vary in which range?
Also, which range do you want to use for s1?

Comment: The replacement rule in your `Mfff` definition is bound to slow things down, as `ReplaceAll` is a top level thing that is slow compared to the other operations in there. Why not do that replacement once and for all, and define `Mfff` as the result?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.